# XMPPFramework Single User Chat in iOS

Tags: ios, xmpp, chat, ejabberd, xmppframework

I am in the process of developing an chat app in iOS. The `XMPP` server is an ejabberd server which is up and running. I got to know from `SO` that there is no need to do any configuration in `ejabberd.cfg` for Single user chat.

I went ahead and started coding and created room (though I was kicked out after 60 seconds after the creation  of room) using robbiehanson `xmppframework`.

Later I realized ( after breaking my head for 2 days and 2 sleepless nights) that room is not something which comes into picture for a single user chat.

When I was searching for an entry point to start with the single user chat I was not able to find a proper guide, sample code snippets to start with. 
But in many of the SO post, I got to know that it is something easy to accomplish. Could anyone please guide me an entry point as how to start a single user chat session

As of now, I have all the rosters as a list. Each row of the list has a link which is a friend's/contact's name. Clicking on the link should open a chat window ( I have created a chat client in story board ).What I need is clicking on a link, how do I initiate a single user chat session with the user. Any advice will be valuable for me to start up with. Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 0):

XMPPFramework contains a [sample](https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework) project from which you could get a basic idea of initial set up. As you said, when you click on a roster, you will be navigated to the chat screen of corresponding user.

Create NSXMLElement with from, to, message and type (type will be "chat"). And then send this message over xmppstream instance. You will be able to know whether your message has been sent or not in delegate methods,

- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didSendMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message
- (void)xmppStream:(XMPPStream *)sender didFailToSendMessage:(XMPPMessage *)message error:(NSError *)error

Happy coding :)